# Excel 2010 hangs when entering data direct into a cell but allows pasting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a couple of largish (20Meg) workbooks with multiple sheets. On one sheet in each work book attempting to add data to the bottom of a list of cells causes the system to hang and leaves no option but to use task manager to close. Pasting the same data into the same cells however does work.

There are no macros in either Workbook lots of lookups though. One contains conditional formatting and one does not.

The issue only occurs on One sheet in each Workbook. This sheet is the subject of lookups but has no formulas or conditional formatting on it.

I've tried with a copy of the file saved locally and one on a network drive with the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in that version of Excel, probably fixed in the next, so you might want to try that, if not, be sure to run update to get the latest bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what we can do with this as it appear this issue is just too local to your set up. It is therefore unlikely (not impossible) that people have experienced this before.

However, in this situation, the way I'd approach the fix is to use the process of elimination.

Save a copy of your file as we will be destructive.

First off, try removing worksheets, one at a time, until you find if one of them has the error. This will make life easy as you've already begun to limit where it is. If this doesn't help, then it may be something that exists over multiple worksheets!!

You mentioned that you don't have any macros etc, but I'll include the detail here to keep the answer complete... Start to remove formula/formatting/macros/Conditional formatting etc, one at a time until you find the thing which causes the error.

At that point, when you find the error, you need to determine if you need that functionality and if it can be achieved another way.

I suspect that as you change the cell, it is causing Excel to re-calculate all sheets. To test, in the Formulas tab, click on Calcuation Options and choose it to manual. See if the same issue occurs when you type into the cell(s). Then click Calculate Now (or Calculate Sheet) and see how it responds.